# Design circle with four clickable areas

Tags: android, android-layout, geometry, android-button

I am new to Android. Please help me in my application.

I want to develop a circle with four button areas.You can find that in [this link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.medisafe.android.client&hl=en). See the screen shots. I want to develop these type of layout in Android. Please give some suggestions. How will I do that?

In that morning,night,noon,evening areas are buttons. I want that type of layout with same buttons future type thing.

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge the easiest way is to create images according that shape and set them as the background image of the button. Then align the buttons in order.
Hope my answer helped you.

Comment: No man,I want so dynamic type of thing. If i do that procedure than tell me how can i adjust that into different screen sizes.

Comment: he is correct. That would be the easiest way. Also, android will re-size the image based on screen-size if you code it correctly. You will probably have to create your own custom view or edit the parameters of the imageView you display.

Answer (score 1):

kevin already posted very easy solution, but the second one would be to create a custom component deriving from `View` and to override `onTouchEvent` method:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int eventaction = event.getAction();

    switch (eventaction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
            // Here get x, y coordinates where exactly component was clicked - which part of a circle 
            break;
    }

    return true; 
}
```

You can get coordinates from `event` object: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try radial-menu-widget open source project available on google code project below link

https://code.google.com/p/radial-menu-widget/

and you can download source code from abvoe link and it's output like below figure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put that type of image as the backgroud in layout. And in that layout u can place the button images ..

Comment: Hey, i taken that as images.. But i didn't get the correct circle. Ok if i get the circle in one screen but i think that is changed to another screen.  can i get any link images adjust to dynamic.